# dataset and UDFs using sapply

Tags: r

I have a dataset (employee) created from a csv, that displays data as given below;

```
employee[1,]

age name designation
28 Tony Manager
```

I have created a function that returns a decision based on an input parameter;

```
   loan_eligible_decision <- function(p)
{
  if(p$designation == "manager")
  {
    decision <- "yes"
  }
  return(decision)
}
```

when the function is called directly it works fine and gives the result below;

```
loan_eligible_decision(employee[1,])

gives me output: yes
```

However when called within an sapply family it throws a reference error;

```
sapply(data.frame(employee[1,]),loan_eligible_decision(x))

Error in p$marital : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any suggestions as to what could be a possible workaround/solution?

I have also tried replacing the if condition with;

```
if(p[[designation]] == "manager")
```

and called upon the function like so;

```
sapply(employee['1',],loan_eligible_decision(x))

The error:
Error in loan_eligible_decision(x) : object 'designation' not found
```

Comment: That is the wrong way to apply it. For rowwise operations you need to use `apply` with `margin=1`. However this is not the best way to go with R. A vectorized approach (which in this case is using `ifelse`) is the best option. Also you do not need a rowwise operation here.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function incorrectly. It should be

```
myfun <- function(x) x^2

sapply(xy, FUN = myfun)
```

In any case, try inserting a `browser()` call within the function and inspect what is going on. See `?browser` for more info.

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  browser()
  x^2
}
```

Comment: I tried this and still face an issue: `x<-employee[1,]`
`x[4]`
_designation_
_1 manager_
`apply(x, 4, function(x)
{
  if(x$designation == "manager")
  {
    decision <- "yes"
  }else{
    decision <- "no" 
  }
  return(decision)
})`

Error:
`Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Comment: @Avin I still dont understand why won't you just use `ifelse(df$designation == 'manager', 'yes', 'no')`. As far as your `apply` goes...many things are wrong, starting with the `4` as a margin,  the `if` statement with using `<-`,  where is `deision` defined? etc.

Comment: Thank you @sotos. Just to clarify I am trying to look at the possibility of an integration of dataframe+UDF+sapply and how compatible they are, I am sure ifelse will give me the result so I have made the changes you suggested, but I wanna know how apply works with the same data. I am stuck with the error:
`Error in if (d2 == 0L) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE` Current Code : `apply(x, 4, function(x){  ifelse(x$marital == 'manager', 'yes', 'no') })`

Comment: 4 is not a valid margin. Something like `sapply(df$designation, function(i) if (i == 'manager'){'yes'}else{'no'})` should work (untested)

Comment: Thank you once again, I am new to R hence the questions @Sotos. I have one last favor to ask. What is my df has 100 records and I have to use another apply to read through those records and perform this operation? Something like this;`sapply(df,function(x) sapply(df$designation, function(x) if (x == 'manager'){ "yes" }else{ "no"}))`